# what does paper.path() with no arguments mean?

Tags: svg, raphael

Im sure of `paper.path("path string")` .But some examples use `path` method with no arguments.
I looked into the docs `paper.path`, its saying the path string is optional, but it hasn't said what happens when there is no path string.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that it allows empty paths. The definition from W3C is:

```
svg-path:
    wsp* moveto-drawto-command-groups? wsp*
```

allowing any amount of white space surrounding zero or one of the `moveto/drawto` command groups.

From [that W3C documentation page](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData):

> Note that the BNF allows the path ‘d’ attribute to be empty. This is not an error, instead it disables rendering of the path.

In other words, it's a path with no elements in it. Without this, you'd probably have to have some kludge like `m 0 0` if you wanted a path to do nothing.